# The meaning of "fully realized" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the meaning of "realized" but in the following sentence, I cannot establish any meaningful relationship between it and the text!

> A closely related theory sees theater as evolving out of dances that
>   are primarily pantomimic, rhythmical or gymnastic, or from imitations
>   of animal noises and sounds. Admiration for the performer’s skill,
>   virtuosity, and grace are seen as motivation for elaborating the
>   activities into **fully realized** theatrical performances.

Comment: What do you understand “realized” to mean? There are multiple meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realized = transformed into a *real* thing.

Just like "carbonized" = transformed into "carbon" [by burning it]. Or "urbanized" = transformed into a city-like place.

I couldn't find this exact sense in the on-line dictionary ([MacMillan on-line](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/realize?q=realized)), but definition #3 is close:

> to achieve something that you have planned or hoped for

In this case, nobody was "planning" or "hoping for" the development of theatrical performances, but the word just means that they fully became reality; it happened.